# Google Navigation send Navigation Markers via Bluetooth

Tags: google-maps, android-maps, android-bluetooth

I want to develop an Application/Plugin? which is able to send the **Navigation Markers** like Left Turn, Right Turn, Roundabout, Fork Left, Fork Right, Slight Left, Slight Right etc. from my **Android Device** via **Bluetooth** to another Device.

Is this possible with a plugin of **Google maps**? an how?

I searched a lot, but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need ideas, an app named [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix)  does this.  It will let you route Google Nav audio via Bluetooth A2DP, Bluetooth Mono, or any other audio output.  It even has settings to route Text-To-Speech audio separate from media audio.